# Understanding Red Block Evaluation

Tags: rebol, red

Just starting with Red and am having a difficult time understanding how to evaluate blocks. The following gives me a `*** Script Error: panel has no value` error:

```
Red [ 
    needs: 'view
]

my-panel: [
    panel 300x300 [
        text "World"
    ]
]

view [
    title "Hello"

    do my-panel
]
```

I can get it working if I inline the contents of the `my-panel` block, but can't find a way to split code up and then include it inside the view function's block. Could anyone give me a real quick pointer to what is wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Red language contains several DSLs, the one you are using above after `view` call is [VID](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/vid.html). The `do` word has different meanings in different contexts. In Red regular language, it evaluates a block of Red Code, in VID, it's a keyword, that allows to embed Red code into VID. So far so good, but you are not passing a block of Red code to `do`, but a block of VID code.

I guess that you want to achieve is inserting the `my-panel` block dynamically. That can be achieved using different means, the easiest would be using `compose` function:

```
Red [ 
    needs: 'view
]

my-panel: [
    panel 300x300 [
        text "World"
    ]
]

view compose [
    title "Hello"

    (my-panel)
]
```

We have several [chat rooms](https://gitter.im/red/help) on Gitter in case you need a more interactive help.

Cheers!